# Comparing the values within SQLite tables across databases in Python 3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.x

I am trying to write a method that compares the values within a given SQLite database table to a another preexisting database table. I have already written a "describe" method for the given database that for every table in the database, the following tuple is appended to an array:

```
databaseInfo.append((table, numberOfColumns, numberOfRows, numberOfCells))
```

Now I am trying to iterate over the columns and rows of each table to see if the value exists within my preexisting database. In doing so, I have set up the following variables:

```
tables = [str(i[0]) for i in databaseInfo]
columns = [int(i[1]) for i in databaseInfo]
rows = [int(i[2]) for i in databaseInfo]
cells = [int(i[3]) for i in databaseInfo]
```

So what I am asking is how can I use sqlite commands to iterate over the cells of the database and compare them. I am seeking the logic/syntax of how I will be able to do so.

For example, if I am given a database with 4 tables, I want to make a method that for each table, it will run through and check if the value of each cell to see if it already exists in my database. So I would like to do something like the following:

Say we have two tables

My Table:

```
+----+-------+-----+---------------+   
| pk | name  | age |  occupation   |
+----+-------+-----+---------------+
|  0 | Joey  |  17 | Student       |
|  1 | Jerry |  18 | Student       |
|  2 | Gabe  |  20 | Mathematician |
|  3 | Ian   |  34 | Unemployed    |
|  4 | Rob   |  33 | Teacher       |
|  5 | Harry |  18 | Student       |
|  6 | Joey  |  20 | Economist     |
|  7 | Jerry |  33 | Coach         |
+----+-------+-----+---------------+
```

Given table:

```
+----+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
| pk | Husband        | height(decimeters) |  occupation   |
+----+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  0 | Joey           |  16                | Student       |
|  1 | Jim            |  17                | Programmer    |
|  2 | Joey           |  16                | Teacher       |
|  3 | Jerry          |  20                | Unemployed    |
|  4 | Tim            |  13                | Unemployed    |
|  5 | Harry          |  18                | Programmer    |
|  6 | Steve          |  18                | Economist     |
|  7 | Jerry          |  11                | Painter       |
+----+----------------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Given that I can describe the given table with my python method, I would like to make the cursor for each database, read through the given table and be able to identify and alter the values that are redundant relative to my database. For example, say that I want to replace every redundant value with "redundant!" Returning a table like this:

```
ColumnsToExclude = pk 

╔════╦════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ pk ║  Husband   ║ height(decimeters) ║ occupation ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════╣
║  0 ║ redundant! ║ 16                 ║ redundant! ║
║  1 ║ Jim        ║ redundant!         ║ Programmer ║
║  2 ║ redundant! ║ 16                 ║ redundant! ║
║  3 ║ redundant! ║ redundant!         ║ redundant! ║
║  4 ║ Tim        ║ 13                 ║ redundant! ║
║  5 ║ redundant! ║ redundant!         ║ Programmer ║
║  6 ║ Steve      ║ redundant!         ║ redundant! ║
║  7 ║ redundant! ║ 11                 ║ Painter    ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Show some specific examples.

Comment: @CL. I have added an example of this but with lists. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: Lists are not tables (and the difference matters). Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: Does my edit suffice? @CL. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: What makes a value redundant? The result does not appear to match the example data.

Comment: Im sorry, my mistake - I made a couple of mistakes on the sample table that now should be fixed. A value is redundant when it appears at least once in my database. @CL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible to construct an SQL query to look up the values in the corresponding column of the other table:

```sql
SELECT pk,
       CASE
         WHEN Husband    IN (SELECT Husband    FROM MyTable)
         THEN 'redundant!' ELSE Husband
       END AS Husband,
       CASE
         WHEN height     IN (SELECT age        FROM MyTable)
         THEN 'redundant!' ELSE height
       END AS height,
       CASE
         WHEN occupation IN (SELECT occupation FROM MyTable)
         THEN 'redundant!' ELSE occupation
       END AS occupation
FROM GivenTable;
```

The table and column names would have to be customized according to whatever tables you want to match.

Comment: This is great! However, when executing this in python, you always need to specify a specific database cursor. Do you think that setting MyTable to givenDatabaseCursor.execute(SELECT givenDatabase) and then use the % to insert it to this argument?

Comment: I do not understand what you are describing. Anyway, try it out, or ask a new question.